# Meaning of “Dear” in context

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, letter-writing

is there any difference between the meaning of the word "Dear" in the letter as greeting? 
For example:

- > Dear Dr. Tse,
- > Dear Mom and Dad,

I think there might be a difference in the meaning of these two greetings. The first one shows respect and the second one affection. Am I right?

Comment: Dear can mean 'much loved', e.g. my dear mother, baby, sister, etc, but when it is used at the start of a letter, e.g. Dear President Trump, it usually does not have that meaning. It is just a convention.

Comment: Yes. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dear) shows the contrast better than some other dictionaries: **dear** ... (5)  A formal way to start (possibly after my) addressing somebody at the beginning of a letter, memo etc.
_Dear Sir/Madam/Miss, please notice our offices will be closed during the following bank holidays_ ...  // (6) 
A formal way to start (often after my) addressing somebody one likes or regards kindly. 
_My dear friend, I feel better as soon as you come sit beside my sickbed!_ Though it does not specify the fact that usage (5) is one bleached of emotion, affection.

Comment: Of course "Deer Bambi" means something else entirely.

Answer (score -1):

Though the use of a “Dear” in business letters seems informal, it is a widely accepted way to address managers or directors. Of course, *Dear dad* implies a level of familiarity and conveys a more personal approach.

The  following extract from  [The Grammarphobia](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2011/08/dear.html)explains how the usage of “Dear” in business and personal letter evolved:

> ***The tradition of using “dear” in letters dates from the mid-15th century.***
>
> It was first recorded, according to OED citations, in a letter beginning “Right dere and welbeloved,” written in 1450 by Queen Margaret of Anjou, wife of King Henry VI.
>
> As the OED says, uses of “dear” in letters—as in “Dear Father,” “Dear John,” and so on—“are still affectionate and intimate, and made more so by prefixing My.”
>
> ***But, Oxford continues, “Dear Sir (or Dear Mr. A.) has become since the 17th c. the ordinary polite form of addressing an equal.”***
>
> And not just equals.
>
> Our handy copy of Miss Manners’ Guide to Excruciatingly Correct Behavior, by Judith Martin, recommends that letters to dignitaries include greetings like “Dear Governor Stately,” “Dear Mr. President,” “Dear Mayor Tuff,” and (to a corporate bigwig) “Dear Mr. Pious.”

Comment: From OED: **A. adj.1 Of persons: a. Glorious, noble, honourable, worthy. Obsolete.** OE   Riddle 33 10   *Is min modor mægða cynnes þæs **deorestan***. ++ 1609   W. Shakespeare Troilus & Cressida v. iii. 27   *Life euery man holds **deere** but the **deere** man, Holds honor farre more precious **deere** then life.*  ++ It is a short step to the current meaning of "dear" =  precious; highly monetarily valued; personally highly valued. (The latter being in the current salutation.)